# Let a question always :include its author, how?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, belongs-to, has-and-belongs-to-many

```
class Question < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :author
end

class Author < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :questions
end
```

When I find some questions, I usually need to get their authors at the same time, so I use:

```
Question.find(:all, :include=>:authors)
```

But I don't write the ":include" part everywhere. I hope I can define the "include" somewhere only once, and when I find questions, the author will be automaticly loaded. Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use default_scope. See here for details: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Base.html#M002313

Answer (score 0):

I prefer to use like this:

```
has_many :questions, :include=>:author
```

Comment: this is not the answer for my question. I want to find the *all the questions* with author, but your answer is for "questions of someone" with author. But still thanks:)